# Make floating div containers stay in place as divs above them expand and overlap

Tags: html, css-float, css

I have many rows of three div containers stacked atop each other (like a grid) using float left, each with a hidden overflow using a max-height limit to truncate the contents inside. In order to expand the divs I use :hover on the class to change the max-height to 999px, revealing the contents while the mouse is hovering, however when the hovered div expands the divs below it get smashed down, shift to the right, or drop down below the lowest point of the hovered div, making the divs chaotic and terrible looking.

How can I have the hovered div expand to reveal the contents without it effecting the divs below?

```
.clips   {
    width: 294px;
    max-height: 150px;
    padding: 2px;
    background-color: #EBEBEB;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #666;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
}
.clips:hover {
    max-height: 999px;
}
```

Comment: how are they stacked atop each other if you're floating them? use position:absolute and z-index on your divs.

Comment: I don't see the `float`, please show your work. @Tim it's probably because of the container width though.

Comment: @Tim - if there is not enough width floats will shift down and try to float left again below. I will try z-index and AP. Suggest as an answer?

Comment: @PHPglue: Odd - I had the float attribute in the CSS, but I think I removed it while I was troubleshooting and forgot to put it back in when I posted this. I'll add it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using absolute positioning instead of floats

First you'd need to wrap each row in a relatively positioned block so they will stack and you can position the "cells" inside the "row"

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell">a</div>
    <div class="cell">b</div>
    <div class="cell">c</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell">d</div>
    <div class="cell">e</div>
    <div class="cell">f</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell">g</div>
    <div class="cell">h</div>
</div>
```

Then style it like this

```
.row{
    position: relative;
    height: 20px;
}
.cell{
    width: 33%;
    outline: 1px dashed blue;
    position: absolute;
}
.cell:nth-of-type(1){
    left: 0;
}
.cell:nth-of-type(2){
    left: 33%;
}
.cell:nth-of-type(3){
    left: 66%;
}
.cell:hover{
    height: 200px;
    background: pink;
}
```

Comment: Bravo. I had to make a few adjustments but your solution got me most of the way there. I wonder: could rows be used to contain float-left divs? Or will they always break loose and move around when expanded into? I also used .row:nth-of-type to set the z-index for the rows so that the expanded overflow goes over the rows below it.

Answer (score 0):

try to wrap group of three divs in div. That will prevent floating other divs to the right of expanded.

Comment: No luck. I tried using a div called "row" to wrap each set of three divs adjacent but unfortunately they are not held in place when divs above expand down into them. I even tried setting the width to lock the div row container in place, but it doesn't seem to have any effect, and they still shift and move around in the flow of the float:left behavior.